# Need a search method and a sort method for a catalog

Tags: java, sorting, search

I have a project coming up for a Java class that I need help with. I am honestly not good at Java or passionate about it at all. However, I need to pass this course, so I need some assistance. I'm making a program that acts as an online bookstore. It starts with a main menu:

```
public static void menu(){
     System.out.println("----MAIN MENU----");
    System.out.println("1. View Catalog");
    System.out.println("2. Search Catalog");
    System.out.println("3. Sort Catalog");
    System.out.println("4. Checkout");
    System.out.println("5. Exit");
    System.out.println("Option: ");
    }
```

So far I've made the catalog:

```
public static void viewCatalog(){
    System.out.println("Welcome to the ABC Catalog!");
    System.out.println("Product Description   Product Category   Product Price");
    System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------------------");
    System.out.println("Alumni Drink ware   Gifts                  25.00 ");
    System.out.println("Binders             School Supplies         3.00 ");
    System.out.println("Bookbag             School Supplies        20.00 ");
    System.out.println("Fabulous Desserts   Textbooks              25.00 ");
    System.out.println("Folders             School Supplies         1.00 ");
    System.out.println("Gift Cards          Gifts                  25.00 ");
    System.out.println("Highlighters        School Supplies         1.00 ");
    System.out.println("Jacket              Campus Gear            65.00 ");
    System.out.println("JAVA Programming    Textbooks             150.00 ");
    System.out.println("Network Solutions   Textbooks              75.00 ");
    System.out.println("Pencils             School Supplies         1.00 ");
    System.out.println("Pens                School Supplies         2.00 ");
    System.out.println("Shorts              Campus Gear            10.00 ");
    System.out.println("Sweatshirts         Campus Gear            40.00 ");
    System.out.println("T-Shirts            Campus Gear            15.00 ");
    System.out.println("Web Design Ideas    Textbooks              25.00 ");
    System.out.println("---------------------------------------------------------");
}
```

But I need a way to be able to enter some criteria, search the catalog, and print the matching criteria. I also need a method that sorts the catalog by either increasing price, decreasing price, alphabetical order, category type, or product description. The project has to have at least one object oriented method. I also need a way to add items from the catalog to a cart.

**Any code snippets would be much appreciated.** I'm not interested in any lectures about cheating, so please don't post anything like that. I hope someone will have some sympathy for a Web Dev student who just needs to pass this course in order to move on to courses that I am more passionate about.

Comment: How is this data going to be stored intitially?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a data structure to hold your data. A list is fine for your case. Create Item objects from the data and put them in a list. Code may have errors since I dont have an IDE to test it.

```
class Item
{
   public Item(String d, String c, double p)
   {
      description = d;
      category = c;
      price = p;
   }
   String description;
   String category;
   double price;
}
```

You can make fields private and write setter and getter fields. Now create an Item object for every line in the catalog and add them to a list.

```
List<Item> list = new ArrayList<>();
Item item = new Item("Binders","School Supplies","3.00");
list.add(item);
```

Sort your item by using a custom comparator. This one sorts the list using description field. If you want to sort it decreasing order you can just run a regular sort and reverse the resulting list.

```
void sortByDescription(List<Item> list)
{
     Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<Item>(){
          public int compare(final Item o1, final Item o2){
              return o1.description.compareTo(o2.description);
          }
     });
}

void sortByDescriptionBackwards(List<Item> list)
{
   sortByDescription(list);
   Collections.reverse(list);
}
```

Search method takes a String parameter and looks for a match in all 3 fields of the item object. If it finds a match item is added to a result list and that list is returned. Original list in not changed.

```
List<Item> search(final String searchFor)
{
    List<Item> searchResults = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i = 0; i<list.size(); i++)
    {
        Item item = list.get(i);
        if(item.description.contains(searchFor) ||
             item.category.contains(searchFor) ||
                String.valueOf(item.prize).contains(searchFor) )
       {searchResults.add(item);}
    }
    return searchResults;
}
```

Comment: So for the list items, would you put those in the view catalog method?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I'll try to answer as many as I can:

You can do searching by simply for-looping through an array until you find an entry that matches what you're looking for.

There are a few native sorting methods that use compareTo, but if you need lots of different ways to sort it may be better to write your own.

I'd say, if you only need to sort by one criteria, see if you can use a function from the standard libraries.

Hopefully that helped.